# Is there any way to detect when ga send is finished (promise, callback, event, etc.)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to send an event using ga(), then immediately redirect to another page. If the ga() send isn't complete it is cancelled by the redirect. Is there any mechanism (such as a callback) that I can use to detect when the event has been delivered to GA (or errored out)? I am currently just delaying for a small period of time, but that is non deterministic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is (and it is even called callback): [Hit Callback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#hitcallback). Redirecting after the tracking call indeed the major usecase. E.g the documentation from the example deals with intercepting a form submit, and resubmitting after the form has been sent:

```
// Gets a reference to the form element, assuming
// it contains the id attribute "signup-form".
var form = document.getElementById('signup-form');

// Adds a listener for the "submit" event.
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  // Prevents the browser from submitting the form
  // and thus unloading the current page.
  event.preventDefault();

  // Sends the event to Google Analytics and
  // resubmits the form once the hit is done.
  ga('send', 'event', 'Signup Form', 'submit', {
    hitCallback: function() {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```